# How to include UPI payment URL inside Google QR Code generator URL?

Tags: qr-code, upi

I want to include "upi://pay?pa=8871459686@paytm&pn=Paytm%20Merchant&mc=abc&mode=02&orgid=000000&paytmqr=abcdefg&sign=abc+xyz/pqr/+stu"
this UPI payment link inside Google QR code generator link but when I am adding this link inside the URL ("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=315x315%26chl=") I am only getting "8871459686@paytm" after scanning QR code.

What I tried :
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=315x315%26chl=upi://pay?pa=8871459686@paytm&pn=Paytm%20Merchant&mc=abc&mode=02&orgid=000000&paytmqr=abcdefg&sign=abc+xyz/pqr/+stuchoe=UTF-8%26chld=L

Please can anyone tell me what will be the right way to add this "upi://pay?pa=8871459686@paytm&pn=Paytm%20Merchant&mc=abc&mode=02&orgid=000000&paytmqr=abcdefg&sign=abc+xyz/pqr/+stu" inside google QR code generator link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google api is using "get" method, you should encode your parameter ("upi://pay?pa=8871459686@paytm&pn=Paytm%20Merchant&mc=abc&mode=02&orgid=000000&paytmqr=abcdefg&sign=abc+xyz/pqr/+stu")

In JavaScript & PHP, you can urlencode() function to encode the parameters.

```
variable = urlencode(text)
```

Send URL encoded variable value in google API URL.